# Spark-shell connecting to Mesos stuck at sched.cpp

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

Below are my `spark-defaults.conf` and the output of `spark-shell`

```
$ cat conf/spark-defaults.conf
spark.master                     mesos://172.16.**.***:5050
spark.eventLog.enabled           false
spark.broadcast.compress         false
spark.driver.memory              4g
spark.executor.memory            4g
spark.executor.instances         1

$ bin/spark-shell
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's repl log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults-repl.properties
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.5.2
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_80)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
15/11/15 04:56:11 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
I1115 04:56:12.171797 72994816 sched.cpp:164] Version: 0.25.0
I1115 04:56:12.173741 67641344 sched.cpp:262] New master detected at master@172.16.**.***:5050
I1115 04:56:12.173951 67641344 sched.cpp:272] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
```

It hangs here indefinitely while Mesos Web UI shows that a lot of Spark frameworks were spinning- continuously registering and unregistering until I quit `spark-shell` with Ctrl-C.

[image: Mesos Web UI]

I suspect that it is partly caused by my laptop having multiple ip addresses. When run on server, it continues to the next line, and the usual Scala REPL:

```
I1116 09:53:30.265967 29327 sched.cpp:641] Framework registered with 9d725348-931a-48fb-96f7-d29a4b09f3e8-0242
15/11/16 09:53:30 INFO mesos.MesosSchedulerBackend: Registered as framework ID 9d725348-931a-48fb-96f7-d29a4b09f3e8-0242
15/11/16 09:53:30 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 57810.
15/11/16 09:53:30 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 57810
15/11/16 09:53:30 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/11/16 09:53:30 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 172.16.**.***:57810 with 2.1 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.**.***, 57810)
15/11/16 09:53:30 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/11/16 09:53:30 INFO repl.Main: Created spark context..
Spark context available as sc.
```

I'm running Mesos 0.25.0 built by Mesosphere, and I'm setting `spark.driver.host` to the address that is accessible from all machines in the Mesos cluster. I see that every port open by `spark-shell`'s process is bind either to that IP address or to `*`.

[The most similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867136/spark-shell-connect-to-mesos-hangs-no-credentials-provided-attempting-to-regis) doesn't seem to be helpful, because in this case my laptop should be accessible from the hosts.

I couldn't locate the log files which might contain why the frameworks were unregistered. Where should I look for to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution??

Comment: unfortunately not yet :(

Comment: I am having this same problem, will update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mesos has a very odd notion of how networking works -- in particular, it is important that you can establish *bidirectional* communication between the Master and Framework.  So both sides need to have a mutual network route.  If you run behind NAT or containers, you've run into this before -- usually you need to set `LIBPROCESS_IP` to your publicly accessible IP on the Framework side.  Perhaps this applies to multihomed systems as well, like your laptop.

You can find a bit more information lying around the internet, although it's unfortunately not well documented.  There's [a hint on their Deployment Scripts page](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/deploy-scripts/) though.

Comment: Except that, as I stated above, I'm not behind NAT. I'm using VPN and have bidirectional access using IP addresses; just that my laptop has multiple addresses.

Comment: I am also not behind NAT and have bidirectional access using IP addresses, but this solution worked for me.